# Limitations in A* algorithm

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, a-star, heuristics

I have 2 questions:

1. How its called an algorithm that works as A*, but instead of
   inserting all the neighbors of the selected node in the priority
   queue, it insert only the best k.
2. How its called an algorithm that works as A*, so it insert all the neighbors of the selected node in
   the priority queue, but this priority queue has a limited size h, so
   if in it there are more than h element, the algoritmh drop the worst
   node. I think it is a simple version of SMA*.

I know that these algorithms are not optmal, but they look like to work very well in my project. And I want to know if they have been studied in past. I don't find anything userfull in the internet.

Comment: 1) Sounds like Greedy. Do you want to visit _only_ the best node, or do you want to insert the other neighbors later, when you run out of alternatives? In particular, note that this way the queue will only ever contain one element at a time: You pop one, and you add one (or none).

Comment: To explain better, if any node has 10 neighbors, in the loop the algoritm will add in the OPEN queue only the best (lowest f) 5 neighbors. This afternoon I studied a lot in the book: Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach, Russel Norvig, and meaby this algorithm could be considered a BeamSearch. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes, after skimming the relevant passages, this seems to fit, although "beam search" might be a bit more general, not only about A*-like searches (e.g. without a distance heuristic).

Comment: I agree ith you. I quote directly Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach, Russel Norvig:   "One approach to forward pruning is beam search: on each ply, consider only a “beam” of the n best moves (according to the evaluation function) rather than considering all possible moves. Unfortunately, this approach is rather dangerous because there is no guarantee that the best move will not be pruned away." So I will use this algorith calling it **a type of Beam Search**